Form element doesn't execute submit after button deletion
When button is clicked, click events bubble up to form and execute the proper callbacks. However, after the button is deleted, formSubmitCallback isn't triggered which theoretically should be, due to the submit event. I can't find exactly why this happens. Is the submit event called somehow after the DOM is updated? I'm not looking for a solution to this, but rather an explanation for the behavior.
HTML:
<form onsubmit="formSubmitCallback()" onclick="formClickCallback()">
  <div onclick="divCallback()">
    <button id="button" onclick="buttonCallback()">
      click me
    </button>
  </div>
</form>

JS:
function buttonCallback() {
  console.log("button")
  document.getElementById("button").remove()
}

function divCallback() {
  console.log("div")
}

function formClickCallback() {
console.log("form click")
}

function formSubmitCallback() {
  console.log("form submit")
}

Result:
"button"
"div"
"form click"


Quite old already (from 2010), but probably still worth a read: If you delete a DOM element, do any events that started with that element continue to bubble?

Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I guess I should have googled the question more broadly.

The reason for this behavior is how the event listners get triggered. If you remove the line
  document.getElementById("button").remove()

and log the eventListners on

control->submit
and
mouse->click

to the console, You will see on the console that the order of the events get triggered are

and the form submitter is the button that we're trying to remove.
So if you remove the button, there won't be a submitter for the form and there for will not trigger the submit action.
